# change x axis scale, which is timestamp, using python plt and pands

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot time series data from DataFrame in pandas using plt.plot.

My data is like[image]

and the plot figure is [image]

I want to change the axis scale from 16:00:00 to 18:00:00 with 5 scales.

Is there a good way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

According to the [documentation of pandas.DataFrame.plot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) you should set the xlim and xticks parameters accordingly. xlim takes two tuples, the lower and upper bound, xticks should contain your tick mark values.

Comment: It would have been better id you would have provided the code to solve it, rather than a general idea.

Comment: That is not very easy as there is no code give to start with, the documentation is pretty clear and since OP already has the plot I think it is just a matter of modifying the already existing code,

Comment: I believe it's better to put this into comment then :(